# Is it possible to construct a Turing Submachine such that a regular turing machine can decide whether the TSM halts but the TSM cannot

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

Is it possible to construct a not fully turing complete version of a turing machine such that a regular turing machine can solve the halting problem for the Turing Submachine but the Turing Submachine cannot solve it's own halting problem.

Comment: What is a 'partial turing machine'?

Comment: Its a bit general and hard to understand. What would be the halting problem in the PTM? what does it mean to "halt" there, and how would you define the language it computes?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "not fully turing complete version of a turing machine".  That's a category error.  A programming language can be Turing complete or not.  A single Turing machine cannot.  It's not clear what a "Turing Submachine is".  I think you'll need to state the question clearly and precisely before it can be answered.  Please define all terms carefully.  It might also help to provide some context and motivation (what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? why are you asking? what are you hoping to learn?).

Answer (score 1):

If I underestand the question, Turing machines that don't make left-moves could be such a TSM. Their transition function is $\delta : Q\times\Gamma\to Q\times\Gamma\times M$, where $Q$ the set of states, $\Gamma$ the tape alphabet and $M=\{S, R\}$ is the set of possible moves for the tape's head. $R$ moves the tape's head to the right and $S$ leaves it at the same cell.

When reading an input, this machine might halt, but might also loop by repeatedly reading and writing at the same tape cell forever. But given such a TSM, we can make a DFA that accepts all the words accepted and rejected by the TSM, and rejects the words for which the TSM loops.

The basic idea is to merge every pair of transitions of the form $q_1\overset{x\mapsto y/S}{\longrightarrow} q_2$ and $q_2\overset{y\mapsto z/R}{\longrightarrow} q_3$ of the TSM into a transition $q_1\overset{x\mapsto z/R}{\longrightarrow} q_3$. Do this repeatedly until there are no more pairs left to merge (this is a terminating process). After this process, if there are still $S$-transitions, these indicate a loop.

If you adapt this idea to your TM and DFA definitions** and further work out the details, you are left with a TSM that simulates a DFA, therefore it always halts. It accepts when the original TSM accepts or rejects and it rejects when the original TSM loops.

** In some cases you might need to do some pre-processing. For example, if you are working with a TM/TSM definition that uses a special rejecting state $q_r$, then before applying the above idea, all of $q_r$'s incoming transitions should become incoming to $q_a$, the accepting state.